# Unable to start BitcoinCore: Unable to start HTTP server. See debug logs for details

Tags: bitcoin-core, windows

After long time of not running Bitcoin Core I ran it and got:

[image]

Config file was:

```
 # server=1 tells Bitcoin-QT to accept JSON-RPC commands.
server=1

 # You must set rpcuser and rpcpassword to secure the JSON-RPC api
rpcuser=user
rpcpassword=password
```

According to [recommendations from other post](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/88419/54914), I have added this to config file

```
# added
rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0
rpcbind=127.0.0.1
rpcbind=bitcoind
```

but it didn't help.

Log file is following

```
2022-10-28T21:02:52Z Binding RPC on address 127.0.0.1 port 8332 failed.
2022-10-28T21:02:54Z libevent: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
2022-10-28T21:02:54Z Binding RPC on address bitcoind port 8332 failed.
2022-10-28T21:02:54Z Unable to bind any endpoint for RPC server
2022-10-28T21:02:54Z Error: Unable to start HTTP server. See debug log for details.
2022-10-28T21:02:58Z Shutdown: In progress...
2022-10-28T21:02:58Z scheduler thread exit
2022-10-28T21:02:58Z Shutdown: done
```

What else can be done?

Answer (score 0):

```
rpcbind=bitcoind
```

In the question you referred to, "bitcoind" is supposed to be the network-name of the computer on which bitcoin is running.

> ```
> # local DNS name (container name used in my Docker Compose file)
> rpcbind=bitcoind
> ```

Open a command prompt window and type the command `hostname` to find out the network name of your computer. If the hostname shown is squonk, double check it by using the command `nslookup squonk` or equivalent (e.g. `dig squonk` or `host squonk` on Linux)

The clue in your log file is this pair of lines

```
libevent: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
Binding RPC on address bitcoind port 8332 failed.
```

If you run bitcoind with the -help option it tells you

```
  -rpcbind=<addr>[:port]
       Bind to given address to listen for JSON-RPC connections. Do not expose
       the RPC server to untrusted networks such as the public internet!
       This option is ignored unless -rpcallowip is also passed. Port is
       optional and overrides -rpcport. Use [host]:port notation for
       IPv6. This option can be specified multiple times (default:
       127.0.0.1 and ::1 i.e., localhost)
```

You could then change the line in the configurartion file

```
rpcbind=squonk
```

Your extract from the log file omits the line before

```
Binding RPC on address 127.0.0.1 port 8332 failed.
```

But those few lines before the above may tell you about a more important problem that is the root cause of your difficulties.